# CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: .net

Trying to make a newsbulletin, that fetches news-api to an SQL and then renders it in an MVC .Net

I get the above issue and I just cant figure it out. I am trying to create a list of posts of NewsArticles

and this code just doesnt want to do what I want:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Article)
            .WithMany(na => na.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ArticleId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);  
    }
```

I tried going through my namespaces, tried using intellisense, ReSharper and just online tools. I just cant understand it.

Comment: Check the type of your Comments property. `WithMany` implies that it should be a collection. If it's just one thing, like a `string`, that would cause an error like this.

Comment: Thank you so much. It means I need to parse it first. It is just one long string with keywords. Like article-id, title. so forth.